# Bracha on Coconut Wraps

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, fruits

[image]

What bracha would these be? The first ingredient is coconut meat. These are all of the ingredients:  Organic Coconut Meat, Organic Coconut Water, Organic Extra Virgin Coconut Oil.

Comment: im litterly having them for supper right now, i wahsed on bread so there would be no sheila but asking for the future

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya, user15604. Remember that you can edit your profile and make it a bit more personal. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Since it has the star K on it, you can call 410 484-4110 9AM to 5 PM to find out if the prodect has been processed in such a way as to make it shehakol or if it is ha-aitz.

Answer (score 1):

Provided it is not eaten as secondary (*tafel*) to another, more significant food (in which case it would not merit its own blessing), and assuming the meat is broken up beyond recognition as coconut (as seems to be the case in, e.g., [this recipe](http://thecoconutmama.com/coconut-wraps-recipe/)), it would seem that, according to at least most *Ashkenazic* authorities, the *bracha* should be *shehakol*.  For a similar ruling regarding applesauce, see, e.g. [here](https://oukosher.org/guide-to-blessings/):

> Apple Sauce | Shehakol | Borei Nefashot | Shehakol is to be said if the apples are totally pureed. This applies mostly to commercially available canned or bottled apple sauce. However, Ha-aytz applies for homemade apple sauce where the applesauce is chunky.

However, according to many rabbinic opinions the correct blessing is actually *haeitz* or even *ha'adama*.  See, e.g., [Halachipedia's article on the topic](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Processed_fruits_and_vegetables):

> If one grinds a vegetable or fruit, whether or not one cooks it, if the vegetable is still recognizable in the product then the Bracha is the same the vegetable, however if it’s ground and unrecognizable then the Bracha is shehakol. According to Sephardic practice, the Bracha does not change, even if the fruit is unrecognizable. Some Ashkenazi poskim maintain that the Bracha for tree-fruits becomes Ha'adama, but the Bracha for vegetables remains the same...
>
> The Gemara Brachot 38a concludes that the Bracha for Tarima (processed dates) is HaEtz because the actual fruit remains. Rashi (D”H Tarima) explains that Tarima is dates which were crushed but not pulverized. However, Rambam (Brachot 8:4) explains that even if one removed the pits and crushed it and kneaded it into a dough the Bracha would still be HaEtz. The S”A 202:7 rules like the Rambam and the Rama rules like Rashi. Yalkut Yosef 202:22 and Halacha Brurah 202:25 rule like Shulchan Aruch, that even if the fruit or vegetable is completely pulverized, the Bracha does not change.
>
> The Mishna Brurah 208:42 concludes that whenever the fruit is recognizable (because of the form and texture) the Bracha would be like the fruit, however, when it’s so processed that it’s not recognizable the bracha is Shehakol. Vezot HaBracha (pg 100, chapter 12) and Veten Bracha (Halachos of Brochos by Rabbi Bodner pg 403-4, chapter 22) agree.
>
> However, the Laws of Brachos (Rabbi Forst, pg 303-5) explains the Mishna Brurah as saying that even for an unrecognizable pulp one should make the bracha of the original fruit. Only something which completely lost it's solid form is shehakol. He therefore writes that apple sauce is HaEtz, and mashed potatoes and peanut butter are HaAdama.
>
> Rabbi Hershel Schachter in Brachot Ha'nehenin (31:15) quotes an alternative approach from Rabbi Soloveitchik; Rosh (Brachot 6:18) writes that for the Bracha of Ha'adama, it is unnecessary for the vegetable to be recognizable. For example, the Bracha for a vegetable broth would be Ha'adama, even though the vegetables were strained out. However, he is unsure if the same rule applies to strained fruit soup. Therefore, Rabbi Soloveitchik felt that it would be preferable to recite Ha'adama on mashed fruits - like applesauce - since Ha'adama is more specific than Shehakol, and Ha'adama doesn't require tzurat ha'pri. Likewise, the Bracha for mashed vegetables would remain Ha'adama. Rabbi Schachter personally follows this opinion (See OU Document X-18 and HalachaDoc LG-A9).

According to all authorities, the blessing after eating an olive-sized amount in the requisite time would be *borei nefashot*.

Comment: note, this answer assumes coconuts are edible

Answer (score -1):

Since the [ingredients to these coconut wraps](https://thrivemarket.com/thrive-market-organic-original-coconut-wraps) are:

> Organic Coconut Meat, Organic Coconut Water, Organic Extra Virgin Coconut Oil

I believe the bracha would be ha'eitz which would make the bracha afterwards borei nefashos.

See [here](http://berachot.org/foods/letter_c.htm) where you can see that the bracha on coconut meat including shredded coconut is ha'eitz.

Comment: @ezra coconuts are fruits, so its ha'etz, right? Is the right thing if its ground to pulp or is oil then shehakol? Also, I do ha'etz on fruit jam and jelly, is that wrong then?